# apply a function on a dataframe in a rolling fashion using values from two columns and previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply

Let's say I have the following dataframe (which in reality is much bigger hence the method should be fast):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"distance1": [101, 102, 103], "distance2":[12, 33, 44]})

    distance1  distance2
0   12           101
1   33           102
2   44           103
```

Now I want to apply following function on this dataframe

```
def distance(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.power(x.loc[n, "distance1"] - x.loc[n-1 ,"distance1"], 2) + np.power(x.loc[n, "distance2"] - x.loc[n-1 ,"distance2"], 2))

data["dist"] = data.apply(distance, axis=1)
```

Where essentially I would calculate the euclidian distance between the distance1 and distance2 and n is the current row, and n-1 is the previous row in the dataframe

Comment: `np.linalg.norm(df['distance1'] - df['distance2'].shift())`.

Comment: the output is nan because I suspect root of negative number. In any case applying this gave nan not a column (or an array) with these values

Comment: should only be `nan` in the first row because of the `shift` operation.

Comment: can it be that shift operator should be places outside of the substraction?

Comment: If none of the answers below address your question appropriately, could you please expand your example a little bit and provide what the expected result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({"distance1": [101, 102, 103], "distance2":[12, 33, 44]})
df['dist'] = np.sqrt((df['distance1'] - df['distance1'].shift(1))**2 + (df['distance2'] - df['distance2'].shift(1))**2)

df.loc[0, 'dist'] = np.nan

print(df)
```

which would give you:

```
   distance1  distance2       dist
0        101         12        NaN
1        102         33  21.023796
2        103         44  11.045361
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```py
z = (df['distance1'] - df['distance2'])**2
out = df.assign(
    cumnorm=np.sqrt(z.cumsum()),
    roll1norm=np.sqrt(z.rolling(1).sum()),
    roll2norm=np.sqrt(z.rolling(2).sum()),
    roll3norm=np.sqrt(z.rolling(3).sum()),
)
>>> out
   distance1  distance2     cumnorm  roll1norm   roll2norm   roll3norm
0        101         12   89.000000       89.0         NaN         NaN
1        102         33  112.614386       69.0  112.614386         NaN
2        103         44  127.133788       59.0   90.785461  127.133788
```

Where:

- `cumnorm` is the "expanding norm" of the first two columns.
- `roll{k}norm` is the norm of `k` rows including the current one.

If you want to avoid the `NaN`s, you could allow less-than-k rows windows:

```py
out = df.assign(
    cumnorm=np.sqrt(z.cumsum()),
    roll1norm=np.sqrt(z.rolling(1, min_periods=0).sum()),
    roll2norm=np.sqrt(z.rolling(2, min_periods=0).sum()),
    roll3norm=np.sqrt(z.rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum()),
)
>>> out
   distance1  distance2     cumnorm  roll1norm   roll2norm   roll3norm
0        101         12   89.000000       89.0   89.000000   89.000000
1        102         33  112.614386       69.0  112.614386  112.614386
2        103         44  127.133788       59.0   90.785461  127.133788
```

IIUC, you are interested in `roll2norm` in one of the two results above.